# User custom input value based decision tree implementation using dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I need following feature in the flow.

- based on users input like gold , silver bot should direct him to those particular credit card flows.
- How to enable loop in flows.
- How to perform 4 to 5 steps long guided flow which is a big complex tree.

[image: The image shows the actual flow that we are trying to make using dialog-flow only]

I have gone through documentations, read about input and output context not of much help but could not get any help in providing hops in the conversation flow as mentioned in the diagram.

Tried using Dialogflow only

I am not able to navigate between the flows.

Comment: When you say "using dialiogflow only" do you mean that you don't want to use fulfillment?

Comment: Hey Pratik, could you solve your problem? Let me know if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to build a basic Action to get familiar with the concepts, check out this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0)

If I understand correctly, you want to ask the user:

"...which one should I tell you about?"

and then the user can say "Silver", "Gold" or "Platinum".

First try to just implement this simple step. Create 4 intents in Dialogflow.

1. Welcome intent, the **response** should be "...which one should I tell you about?"
2. Silver Intent. **Training phrase** should be "Silver", **response** should be "You chose Silver"
3. Gold Intent. **Training phrase** should be "Gold", **response** should be "You chose Gold"
4. Platinum Intent. **Training phrase** should be "Platinum", **response** should be "You chose Platinum"

Once you've done that. Test it! It should trigger the correct intent based on your input. It's very simple to build a "switch" from a flow chart in Dialogflow.

Next step: You can replace Silver/Gold/Platinum with a custom entity, read more about this [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities).

This should already help you implement your flow chart.

In your chart you have currently just one answer for each card type Silver/Gold/Platinum - if you want **more than one step** per card type and need to remember you're still in the **context** of the Silver card - you can use **contexts**. In Dialogflow you can hover over the Silver intent you created earlier and create a follow-up intent. But with your current flow chart it's not necessary.